# function parameters... function check(object){}

Tags: javascript, html, function, parameters

I have a function called `collisioncheck`. Right now it works perfectly by checking variables that apply to a player, such as `playerPosX`, `playerVelX`, `playermaskIMG`, etc.

What I want to do is something like `collisioncheck(object)`, so that say I call `collisioncheck(player)` it will check the variables like above with `playerPosX` etc. and if I call `collisioncheck(zombie)` then it will instead check `zombiePosX`, etc.

How could I do this?

If you have any questions please ask as I am not really very good at explaining this... 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a particular reason in your case not to give the fields the same name in each type? e.g. Just have `posX`, `velX`, `maskIMG`, regardless of whether it is a `player`, `zombie` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple:

```
function collisioncheck(obj) {
  var posX = obj.posX;
  var velX = obj.velX;
  var maskIMG = obj.maskIMG;
}

// ...

var objectToCheck = {
  'posX' : playerPosX,
  'velX' : playerVelX,
  'maskIMG' : playermaskIMG
};

collisioncheck(objectToCheck);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest that you refactor the code so that variables like

```
playerPosX
playerPosY
playerVelX
playerVelY
zombiePosX
zombiePosY
zombieVelX
zombieVelY
```

do not appear in your code.  Instead `zombie` and `player` should be objects with *properties* such as `velX`, `velY`, `posX` and `posY`.

Then `collisionCheck` can look like

```
function collisionCheck(object) {
    .... object.posX ...
}
```

The current object would be compared against all of the other nearby players and zombies by checking each of the properties of these objects.

You really do not want to go the route of dealing with variable names as strings.  In essence, properties do this for you.

Comment: Yes this exactly what I'm looking for! how do I create an object with properties? like what would the syntax for a player object?

Comment: Vlad's answer shows how to create an object with properties.  In order to update such an object you would write code such as `zombie.posX = 4;`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you

```
   zombie = { 'posX' : 7,  'posY' : 95 };
   player = { 'posX' : 3,  'posY' : 95 };
   document.write(  zombie.posX );


    function CollisionCheck ( o1 , o2 )
    {

        if ( Math.abs(o1.posX - o2.posX) < 5 )
            {
                document.write ( 'Kaboom!!!' );              
            }        
    }        
    CollisionCheck ( zombie, player );
```